# Sequelize error when using "where" and "in" on a subarray

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

This is my model definition:

```
var Tag = sequelize.define('Tag', {
    name: Sequelize.STRING
});

var Event = sequelize.define('Event', {
    name: Sequelize.STRING,
});

Event.hasMany(Tag, {as: 'tags', through: 'event_tags', foreignKey: 'eventId'});
Tag.hasMany(Event, {as: 'events', through: 'event_tags', foreignKey: 'tagId'});
```

In words this is: there are events and tags. Events are tagged with many tags.

I'm trying to run this query:

```
Event
.findAndCountAll({
    include: [{model: Tag, as: 'tags'}],
    where: {'tags.id': {in: [1,2,3,4]}},
    order: order,
    limit: pageSize,
    offset: pageSize * (page - 1),
})
.success(function(result) {

    ...
});
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
   \node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\query-generator.js:1134
          var logicResult = Utils.getWhereLogic(logic, hash[key][logic]);
                                                                ^
   TypeError: Cannot read property 'in' of undefined
```

What am I doing wrong?

I've used before the "in" expression, for example here:

```
 Tag
 .find({
      where: {id: {in: [1,2,3,4]}}
 }).success(...)
```

And it worked just fine.

I've never used the in expression with a sub-array though, as in this case. So I don't know if thats the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 219):

No need "in" property, sequelize auto define this. Just set array.

```
Tag.findAll({
    where: {
        id: [1,2,3,4]
    }
}).then(...)
```

Comment: My last piece of code in my question (the one that you are "fixing") is already ok. Please read the entire post:)

Comment: Enxtur, I tried it with findAll and only this way all the records with an id in that array were displayed. Otherwise, only the record with the value of the id equal to the value of the first element in the array will be displayed. Thank you for your help! It was very useful!
Tag.findAll({ where: { id: [0,1,2,3] } }).then( tag => {  res.json( tag ); });

Comment: @Emanuelacolta It was misunderstood question and wrong answer, cause my bad english. But i'm happy for it is useful to someone :)

Comment: other query its work but some condition in my case i got problem with naming export excel because using to long name by filter on in expression then i didnt catch on generate an excel file. ah my bad. i think its not work .

Answer (score 35):

Updated example for Sequelize v5:

```
await Tag.findAll({
  where: {
    id: {
      [Sequelize.Op.in]: [1, 2, 3, 4]
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Just make sure it's ```static``` method not object accessible method.

Comment: It's worth noting the [Shorthand syntax for Op.in section](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html#shorthand-syntax-for--code-op-in--code-) with example: `id: [1,2,3] // Same as using id: { [Op.in]: [1,2,3] }`

Answer (score 1):

I know this is hella old.  But I'm pretty sure what you were looking for is as follows.  At least one of these should do the trick.  Probably both.  I can't test at the moment because I'm in the middle of a 43-files-changed spaghetti code beast.  I'll update with an actual test when I find the time.

(I'm posting now because all the rest seem to not actually answer the question asked, but they did answer the question I had when I arrived here.)

```
Event
.findAndCountAll({
    include: [{model: Tag, as: 'tags'}],
    where: {
      tags: {
        id: {in: [1,2,3,4]}
      }
    },
    order: order,
    limit: pageSize,
    offset: pageSize * (page - 1),
})
.success(function(result) {

    ...
});
```

```
Event
.findAndCountAll({
    include: [
      {
        model: Tag,
        as: 'tags',
        where: { id: {in: [1,2,3,4]} },
      }
    ],
    order: order,
    limit: pageSize,
    offset: pageSize * (page - 1),
})
.success(function(result) {

    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`in` property able to use at version 4.42

```
Tag.findAll({
    where: { id: {in: [1,2,3,4]} }
}).then(...)
```

And you can use `notIn` property for excluded values.

```
Tag.findAll({
    where: { id: {notIn: [1,2,3,4]} }
}).then(...)
```

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/querying.html#operators

Comment: This does not work in `sequelize` version `6`.

Answer (score -7):

replace in with `$in`

```
where : { id : { $in : [1,2,3,4]}}
```

Comment: The above contributor (Jaddu) has confused the syntax in their answer with the similar `$in` operator for MongoDB. It is NOT the same as the `in` operator that Sequelize offers, and the answer provided by Enxtur above, which eliminates the operator altogether in favour of an array value is the correct solution to the problem.

Comment: They aren't confusing it with MongoDB and their answer was still somewhat reasonable in 2018.

https://sequelize.org/v4/manual/tutorial/querying.html
"For backward compatibility reasons Sequelize sets the following aliases by default - $eq, $ne, $gte, $gt, $lte, $lt, $not, $in, $notIn…"

I'm here looking for something else, but that stuck out.