# sequelize nodejs can i findAll the emails in custom array with 1 findAll?

Tags: node.js, arrays, sequelize.js

I am working on a project with sequelize and i have a problem:
I need to find all the emails in a custom array like:

```
const array = ['1234@gmail.com', '14521@gmail.com', '13245@gmail.com']
```

and findAll users where those array elements with only one action,
Can i do that?
I think some thing like this:

```
    const array = ['1234@gmail.com', '14521@gmail.com', '13245@gmail.com']
    const users = await db.Users.findAll({ where: {
        [Op.contains]: array
    }}).then(user => res.send(user));
```

Thanks for your Help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24920427/12761193

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the answer use:

```
    const array = ['123@gmail.com', '456@gmail.com'];

    const users = await db.Users.findAll({where: {
        Email: array
    }}).then(room => res.send(room));
```