# Sequelize: select only chats where user are in

Tags: javascript, mysql, sequelize.js

I have 3 MySQL tables:

- *chats:* id, name
- *chat_members:* id, chat_id, user_id
- *users:* id, name

My sequelize relation defined as:

```
Chat.belongsToMany(User, { as: 'users', through: ChatMember });
```

I'm trying to run the following findAll query:

```
Chat.findAll({ include: ['users'] })
```

but this returns all chats for all users include user records with participants (as needed). However, I need to only return chats for a specific user ID (or multiple ids) and also return a list of all participants.

So I can modify this request:

```
Chat.findAll({ include: ['users'], where: literal(`exists (select * from chat_members where chat_id = chats.id and user_id = ${userId}`) })
```

or for multiple users requests that could be:

```
Chat.findAll({ include: ['users'], where: literal(`exists (select * from chat_members where chat_id = chats.id and user_id IN ${userIds.join(',')}`) })
```

But I see some issues in that approach:

1. **userId**, **userIds** input isn't *mysql-safe*. In that case, I will need to escape all input but I don't know still how to do that properly because AFAIK Sequelize doesn't support "prepare statement" mechanic;
2. I will have to run subquery there which may drastically impact SELECT query performance;
3. Statement in the subquery is built outside of ORM control. I will have to maintain that line separately if the table name or structure changes

So I expect different approaches for solving the downside issues of my current implementation.

Thanks

Comment: Can you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24920427/sequelize-error-when-using-where-and-in-on-a-subarray) one

Comment: @GirishSrivatsa well. I guess my problem is different.. I want to select chats that have a particular user in them and also select ALL participants